# Trying to study about homeomorphism, local diffeomorphism, diffeomorphism.

Tags: diffeomorphism

If I am given a function, how can I tell if it is a homeomorphism, local diffeomorphism, or diffeomorphism. Does one imply the other(s)?

(I just started studying this topic and having a hard time understanding it. It's quite confusing. I think some organized answers for this question will really help me understand the whole notion clearly. Thank you in advance!)

Comment: Homeomorphisms won’t preserve the differentiable structure

Comment: A homeomorphism that is a local diffeomorphism at every point is a diffeomorphism